# Symfony 4 - Failed opening required getSwiftmailer_EmailSender_ListenerService

Tags: php, symfony, docker, swiftmailer, symfony4

I want to check requirements with Symfony 4 : http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/requirements.html

But when I use `composer require requirements-checker` command, I get this error message :

> Fatal error: Container5q18PHK\srcDevDebugProjectContainer::load(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/demo/var/cache/dev/Container5q18PHK/getSwiftmailer_EmailSender_ListenerService.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /var/www/html/demo/var/cache/dev/Container5q18PHK/srcDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 350
>
> In srcDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 350:
> Compile Error: Container5q18PHK\srcDevDebugProjectContainer::load(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/demo/var/cache/dev/Container5q18PHK/getSwiftmailer_EmailSender_ListenerService.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php')

I use a Docker container (php:7.2-fpm).

What is the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by restarting my container...